# Screen flickering on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, composable

I am developing an Android app with composable and whenever I run the emulator the screen of it flickers like dead pixels on a real android phone [image: like this]

I tried deleting and re-adding emulator but still it persist.

I am using Pixel XL with API 33 (ABI x86_64 Android Tiramisu)

Configuration of laptop : AMD Ryzen 5 4600H, 8 Gb Ram

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have provided more memory for the emulator and the issue disappeared
[image]

Comment: This solution was the one that worked best for me!